# Why I can't get int/string from intent in android home/launcher activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I use the following code to switch to android home/launcher activity:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
sendIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sendIntent.putExtra("nameInt", 100);
sendIntent.putExtra("nameString", String("100");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

and the home activity was sucessfully launchered. however, when I using following code trying to get extras in home activity onStart(), I cant get the extra from intent?

```
Intent receiveIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = receiveIntent.getIntExtra("nameInt", -1);  // return default -1
String stringValue = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("nameString"); // nothing return
```

any one can help me?

Comment: does it throw an error or what does it?

Comment: @silvia_aut it says that it returns default in the code comments

Comment: are you sure that code does get called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The launcher will be running with `launchMode="singleInstance"`. This means that when you "launch" the launcher, you aren't creating a new instance, you are just bringing the existing instance forward. In `onStart()`, calling `getIntent()` will return the **`Intent` that was used to start the activity for the first time**. That `Intent` won't have any extras, since it was started by the Android framework, not you.

You should check for the extras in `onNewIntent()`, which should be called with the `Intent` that you used to launch the launcher.

Comment: hi David,I add flag : FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in in sendIntent. however, onNewIntent() is not called at all.
meanwhile, I found a interested action: all extra can received from intent in onStart() if I specified the home/launcher activity in sendIntent.
sendIntent.setClassName("home packageName", "home activity name");

Answer (score 1):

Change This

```
sendIntent.putExtra("nameString", String("100");
```

To This

`sendIntent.putExtra("nameString", "100");`